# Get value from multiple checkboxes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Following is my code in which I am trying to get values of multiple checkboxes selected, but some how its not working. Let me know what I am doing wrong here, BTW the list is dynamic and not going to contain only 3 items in an array.

My Plnkr - [PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWQsH0Ne6YTtf5w1ThWX?p=preview)

HTML -

```
    <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in studentList">
   <td ng-bind="$index + 1"></td>
   <td ng-bind="student.email"></td>
   <td ng-bind="student.fname"></td>
   <td ng-bind="student.lname"></td>
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="studcheck" ng-value="$index" />
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
{{studcheck}}
```

CONTROLLER CODE -

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.studentList = [
    {email: 'test1@gmail.com', fname: 'Test1', lname: 'Last1' },
    {email: 'test2@gmail.com', fname: 'Test2', lname: 'Last2' },
    {email: 'test3@gmail.com', fname: 'Test3', lname: 'Last3' },
  ];

  $scope.studcheck = {};
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `ng-model` multiple times on the same model, but here just specify the key and it should be fine:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="studcheck[$index]" ng-value="$index" />
```

If you want to update the `student` model to know if it is checked or not, you could try using `ng-change`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="studcheck[$index]" ng-value="$index" ng-change="student.checked = !student.checked" />
```

Comment: You are okay with binding one parameter to all checkboxes, but I believe he is trying to do set different values for each checkbox where ng-value is not works for checkbox...

Comment: `ng-value` is working correctly here. Check the produced HTML, then input value is indeed equal to `$index`.

Comment: can you provide plunker for this?

Comment: Thx a lot..it works !! just as a suggestion I am getting data now like - `{ 1=true, 3=true}` can I improve this too ..means {Student_email: <>, checked: <>} something like this

Comment: As you see you will only get true or false not the value you want... If you look at the documentation ng-value is not an option for checkbox...

Comment: @wickY26 can you please suggest me a way to achieve something like - `[{Student_email: <>, checked: <>} ,{Student_email: <>, checked: <>} ]`  rather than  `{ 1=true, 3=true}`

Comment: @TechSolvr do you want bind checkbox value  to student object?

Comment: @wickY26 yeah bcoz with this solution, I still need to write a loop to check what students are selected

Comment: @TechSolvr just change ur inbox with this <input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.checked"/> and you will see student.checked true or false...